# Django HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url')) Returns NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this tag `<a href = '/mysite/goto_home/Yax/'>Yax</a>`

I want if a user clicks on it, he/she should be redirected to this **URL**:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<user_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.user_profile, name='user_profile')
```

But it's giving me `NoReverseMatch at /mysite/goto_home/Yax/
Reverse for 'user_profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'user_id': 2, 'user_name': u'Mokwa'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mysite/user/(?P<user_id>\\d+)/(?P<user_name>[-\\w]+)/$']`

**Views.py**:

```
def profile(request, user_name):
    try:
        user = Users.objects.get(username = user_name)
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        user = none
        if user is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mysite:user_profile', kwargs={'user_id': int(user.id), 'user_name':user.name}))

def user_profile(request, user_id, user_name):
    pass
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show both your model's `get_absolute_url` method and how you referenced the URL in your template? The link you've shown is `HTML`, which might be the output you've generated but it won't be what the Python interpreter is dealing with.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of just sending them directly to the view via it's own url in the `a` tag anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You used `"mysite:user_profile"` for your reverse call, but the URL is not in a namespace. You should either use just `"user_profile"` or set a namespace for the URLs wrapped in a call to `include`.

Namespaces are explained in greater detail here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: Please I don't understand your answer. I tried `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_profile', kwargs={'user_id': int(user.id), 'user_name':user.name}))` and I still get the same error.